# FLS metadata for a custom field

Tags: custom-field, metadata, fls

Where can I find the FLS metadata for a field? In which component metadata I can find the FLS for a field given to profiles?

Comment: Plesae check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544295/salesforce-metadata-api-customfield-set-field-level-security

Answer (score 1):

FLS is stored in the profiles themselves (which helps explain why FLS is not deployed to an org when you deploy the field to a new org).

The other possible location is in a PermissionSet.

Comment: Indeed, retrieving profiles includes `fieldPermissions` (and `objectPermissions`) elements for the various fields that the user has been granted at least read permission for. Note, however, that CRUD/FLS permissions *should* be managed via permission sets and permission set groups instead of profiles. Additionally, to identify a given user's specific capabilities requires combining CRUD/FLS from their profile, permission set group and permission sets...